# Can Grails 3.3 fields plugin f:display show many-to-many

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class

I'm working with Grails 3.3.9 but I can change that as necessary.

I would like to let the Grails fields plugin manage my CRUD as generated, or at least with minimal manual changes.  The problem I have not been able to solve is when I have a many-to-many relationship and want to show the related instances from either side.

A simple example: two domain classes, Company and Worker.  Each have a String name and each have a hasMany:

```
static hasMany = [companies: Company] // in Worker
static hasMany = [workers: Worker] // in Company
```

I don't identify that either class belongsTo the other.

When I generate-all and run the app, then use Worker / new CRUD to create new instances of Worker, all seems fine.

Then, when I create a company using Company / new CRUD, I am offered a drop-down of the already defined workers, which looks good; so I shift-click on a couple to include them in the new company definition.  But then after the save, the show CRUD does not show a list of selected workers for the Company instance I just created.  There is a field label "Workers" but no value shown next to it.

I can't seem to find any obvious way to encourage f:display to show that list - or maybe somehow the multi-select didn't produce the desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.  Solved my problem.  This page:

https://github.com/grails-fields-plugin/grails-fields/blob/master/grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_list.gsp

shows what the template is (should be?) to render fields.  Wondering if that was somehow different than what's in my version, I installed that file in

...grails-app/views/templates/_fields/_list.gsp

and suddenly my many-to-many relations were visible.

Extra info that may be useful for others stumbling over this:

I followed the GORM reference manual recommendation for creating a many-to-many relationship where each side includes a

```
static hasMany = [...]
```

and the "owned" side also has a

```
static belongsTo =
```

I think I may have been confused as to the meaning of the belongsTo in this case - what it means is well explained here:

http://docs.grails.org/3.0.4/guide/GORM.html#manyToMany

Comment: Hmmm maybe I just needed the belongsTo.  it seems I can now delete that template and all works OK.